# How to get my dwellers back in the shelter after exploring?

Tags: fallout-shelter

After I send my dwellers out to explore and make them return I can't get them bank in the shelter It said they are waiting?

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely be due to the quantity of items in your inventory being greater than your available storage space. Either build more storage or sell some items before allowing this dweller back in.

Comment: To add to @kalina's answer, the way to tell if this is the issue is that some of the items they have collected will have a red background. This is to indicate that you don't have enough storage space. You can mark items for sale in the wanderer's inventory before bringing them in, and they will auto-sell those items upon entering the vault. (I'd like to know who you're selling all this stuff to, to be honest!)